# Five9 Softphone does not support your browser Chrome (linux x86_64) error

Tags: google-chrome, 22.04, chromium, voip, chrome-extension

How can the [Five9 Softphone](https://www.five9.com/connect/softphone-software) extension be made to work with Linux?

[image: browser not supported]

I've tried both `Chromium` and the official `Chrome` from `Google` itself with the same error.

Notably, this plugin is [advertised](https://www.five9.com/blog/what-does-chrome-enterprise-recommended-mean) as working from a `Chromebook`, which, [to my understanding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChromeOS), is a `Linux` based `OS` leading me to think it's a matter, perhaps, of a `kernel` module or other option.

The "solution" for `MacOS` is to just use a specific version of `Java` which sounds good...but I'm doubtful that would work on `Linux`.