# How is ChromeOS run in a VM on Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, google-chrome, virtualization, hardware, chromeos

How is `ChromeOS` run in a `VM` on **`Ubuntu` 22.04 Jammy**?  Preferably, would still boot into `Ubuntu` and then launch something to get the `ChromeOS` to run [specific](https://askubuntu.com/q/1428715/847449) software.  However, dual-boot would be fine.  It's not clear what the maintained [options](https://www.alphr.com/download-install-chrome-os/) are.

There are [references](https://askubuntu.com/q/866590/847449) to various outdated and umaintained projects for doing this on a `Chrome Book`.

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller (rev 04)
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville) (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev b4)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev b4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a4)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Q67 Express Chipset LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 RAID bus controller: Intel Corporation SATA Controller [RAID mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 04)
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ sudo lshw
mordor                      
    description: Desktop Computer
    product: OptiPlex 990
    vendor: Dell Inc.
    version: 01
    serial: C0ZZVR1
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=desktop frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled uuid=4c4c4544-0030-5a10-805a-c3c04f565231
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: 0VNP2H
       vendor: Dell Inc.
       physical id: 0
       version: A00
       serial: /C0ZZVR1/CN73604183027H/
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Dell Inc.
          physical id: 0
          version: A18
          date: 09/24/2013
          size: 64KiB
          capacity: 10MiB
          capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int13floppy1200 int13floppy720 int13floppy2880 int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2400 CPU @ 3.10GHz
          vendor: Intel Corp.
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: 6.42.7
          serial: Not Specified
          slot: CPU 1
          size: 3214MHz
          capacity: 4GHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx lahf_lm epb pti ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid xsaveopt dtherm ida arat pln pts md_clear flush_l1d cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 microcode=47 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 5
             slot: L1-Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             capabilities: internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 6
             slot: L2-Cache
             size: 1MiB
             capacity: 1MiB
             capabilities: internal varies unified
             configuration: level=2
        *-cache:2
             description: L3 cache
             physical id: 7
             slot: L3-Cache
             size: 6MiB
             capacity: 6MiB
             capabilities: internal varies unified
             configuration: level=3
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: 2d
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 16GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: 8JTF51264AZ-1G6E1
             vendor: Micron
             physical id: 0
             serial: 38396F43
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: 8JTF51264AZ-1G6E1
             vendor: Micron
             physical id: 1
             serial: E8A1F9E2
             slot: ChannelA-DIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:2
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: 8JTF51264AZ-1G6E1
             vendor: Micron
             physical id: 2
             serial: 366E34E4
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM0
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
        *-bank:3
             description: DIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1333 MHz (0.8 ns)
             product: M378B5173DB0-CK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 3
             serial: 93F44BA9
             slot: ChannelB-DIMM1
             size: 4GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 1333MHz (0.8ns)
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family DRAM Controller
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 09
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=snb_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             logical name: /dev/fb0
             version: 09
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
             configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 resolution=1280,1024
             resources: irq:28 memory:e0c00000-e0ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-communication:0
             description: Communication controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.0
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=mei_me latency=0
             resources: irq:27 memory:e1ab0000-e1ab000f
        *-communication:1
             description: Serial controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family KT Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 16.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:16.3
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm msi 16550 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=serial latency=0
             resources: irq:17 ioport:30e0(size=8) memory:e1a90000-e1a90fff
        *-network
             description: Ethernet interface
             product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection (Lewisville)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 19
             bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
             logical name: eno1
             version: 04
             serial: 18:03:73:cd:33:ad
             size: 100Mbit/s
             capacity: 1Gbit/s
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
             configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=5.15.0-47-generic duplex=full firmware=0.13-4 ip=192.168.0.107 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
             resources: irq:30 memory:e1a00000-e1a1ffff memory:e1a80000-e1a80fff ioport:3080(size=32)
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1a
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1a.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:16 memory:e1a70000-e1a703ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.15.0-47-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 5.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@1:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=6 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb
                      description: Audio device
                      product: C-Media Electronics Inc. USB Audio Device
                      vendor: C-Media Electronics Inc.
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@1:1.4
                      logical name: card1
                      logical name: /dev/snd/controlC1
                      logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0c
                      logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC1D0p
                      logical name: input7
                      logical name: /dev/input/event3
                      version: 1.00
                      capabilities: usb-1.10 audio-control usb
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
        *-multimedia
             description: Audio device
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family High Definition Audio Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1b
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1b.0
             logical name: card2
             logical name: /dev/snd/controlC2
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC2D0
             logical name: /dev/snd/hwC2D3
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D0c
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D0p
             logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC2D3p
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:29 memory:e1a60000-e1a63fff
           *-input:0
                product: HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
                physical id: 0
                logical name: input12
                logical name: /dev/input/event8
           *-input:1
                product: HDA Intel PCH Front Mic
                physical id: 1
                logical name: input13
                logical name: /dev/input/event9
           *-input:2
                product: HDA Intel PCH Line Out
                physical id: 2
                logical name: input14
                logical name: /dev/input/event10
           *-input:3
                product: HDA Intel PCH Front Headphone
                physical id: 3
                logical name: input15
                logical name: /dev/input/event11
           *-input:4
                product: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
                physical id: 4
                logical name: input16
                logical name: /dev/input/event12
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:4000(size=4096) memory:cfa00000-cfbfffff ioport:cfc00000(size=2097152)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: b4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:e1000000-e19fffff ioport:e0000000(size=10485760)
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family USB Enhanced Host Controller #1
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1d
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1d.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=0
             resources: irq:17 memory:e1a50000-e1a503ff
           *-usbhost
                product: EHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 5.15.0-47-generic ehci_hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 5.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=3 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb
                   description: USB hub
                   product: Integrated Rate Matching Hub
                   vendor: Intel Corp.
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: usb@2:1
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=hub slots=8 speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:0
                      description: Video
                      product: HD Pro Webcam C920
                      vendor: Logitech, Inc.
                      physical id: 4
                      bus info: usb@2:1.4
                      logical name: card0
                      logical name: /dev/snd/controlC0
                      logical name: /dev/snd/pcmC0D0c
                      logical name: input17
                      logical name: /dev/input/event13
                      version: 0.21
                      serial: 133E919F
                      capabilities: usb-2.00 usb
                      configuration: driver=snd-usb-audio maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
                 *-usb:1
                      description: Mouse
                      product: USB Optical Mouse
                      vendor: Primax Electronics, Ltd
                      physical id: 5
                      bus info: usb@2:1.5
                      logical name: input8
                      logical name: /dev/input/event4
                      logical name: /dev/input/mouse0
                      version: 2.00
                      capabilities: usb-2.00 usb
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
                 *-usb:2
                      description: Keyboard
                      product: CASUE CASUE USB Keyboard
                      vendor: CASUE
                      physical id: 6
                      bus info: usb@2:1.6
                      logical name: input10
                      logical name: /dev/input/event6
                      logical name: input11
                      logical name: /dev/input/event7
                      logical name: input9
                      logical name: /dev/input/event5
                      logical name: input9::capslock
                      logical name: input9::compose
                      logical name: input9::kana
                      logical name: input9::numlock
                      logical name: input9::scrolllock
                      version: 0.01
                      capabilities: usb-1.10 usb
                      configuration: driver=usbhid maxpower=100mA speed=2Mbit/s
                 *-usb:3
                      description: Bluetooth wireless interface
                      product: Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
                      vendor: Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd
                      physical id: 7
                      bus info: usb@2:1.7
                      version: 88.91
                      capabilities: bluetooth usb-2.00
                      configuration: driver=btusb speed=12Mbit/s
        *-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 82801 PCI Bridge
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1e
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1e.0
             version: a4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci subtractive_decode bus_master cap_list
             resources: ioport:5000(size=4096) memory:cfe00000-cfffffff ioport:e0a00000(size=2097152)
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: Q67 Express Chipset LPC Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.0
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=lpc_ich latency=0
             resources: irq:0
           *-pnp00:00
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 0
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:01
                product: PnP device PNP0b00
                physical id: 1
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=rtc_cmos
           *-pnp00:02
                product: PnP device INT3f0d
                physical id: 2
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:03
                product: PnP device PNP0501
                physical id: 3
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=serial
           *-pnp00:04
                product: PnP device PNP0c02
                physical id: 4
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
           *-pnp00:05
                product: PnP device PNP0c01
                physical id: 5
                capabilities: pnp
                configuration: driver=system
        *-raid
             description: RAID bus controller
             product: SATA Controller [RAID mode]
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.2
             logical name: scsi0
             logical name: scsi1
             version: 04
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: raid msi pm bus_master cap_list emulated
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=0
             resources: irq:26 ioport:30d0(size=8) ioport:30c0(size=4) ioport:30b0(size=8) ioport:30a0(size=4) ioport:3060(size=32) memory:e1a40000-e1a407ff
           *-disk
                description: ATA Disk
                product: WDC WD2500AAKS-0
                vendor: Western Digital
                physical id: 0
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/sda
                version: 1B01
                serial: WD-WMART0781242
                size: 232GiB (250GB)
                capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
                configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=ec8fbae9-4b92-4f4f-8bd9-2916e8bbbcfa logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
              *-volume:0
                   description: BIOS Boot partition
                   vendor: EFI
                   physical id: 1
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                   logical name: /dev/sda1
                   serial: dd3c1e66-04c9-4312-ac31-8976599e0c7d
                   capacity: 1023KiB
                   capabilities: nofs
              *-volume:1
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: mkfs.fat
                   physical id: 2
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                   logical name: /dev/sda2
                   logical name: /boot/efi
                   logical name: /boot/grub
                   version: FAT32
                   serial: 2442-79d7
                   size: 510MiB
                   capacity: 512MiB
                   capabilities: boot fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat mount.fstype=vfat mount.options=rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro name=EFI System Partition state=mounted
              *-volume:2
                   description: Linux swap volume
                   vendor: Linux
                   physical id: 3
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                   logical name: /dev/sda3
                   version: 1
                   serial: 127e18bb-500b-46fa-bd07-989242efd5e9
                   size: 2047MiB
                   capacity: 2047MiB
                   capabilities: nofs swap initialized
                   configuration: filesystem=swap pagesize=4095
              *-volume:3
                   description: boot partition
                   vendor: Solaris
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                   logical name: /dev/sda4
                   serial: 3c03535a-f0db-8e41-98e1-cc460b59439b
                   capacity: 2047MiB
                   capabilities: boot
              *-volume:4
                   description: root partition
                   vendor: Solaris
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,5
                   logical name: /dev/sda5
                   serial: 27ee4c39-2205-9e42-a698-d77a96268917
                   capacity: 228GiB
           *-cdrom
                description: DVD reader
                product: DVD-ROM TS-H353C
                vendor: TSSTcorp
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
                logical name: /dev/cdrom
                logical name: /dev/sr0
                version: D100
                capabilities: removable audio dvd
                configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
        *-serial
             description: SMBus
             product: 6 Series/C200 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1f.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.3
             version: 04
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             configuration: driver=i801_smbus latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:e1a30000-e1a300ff ioport:3040(size=32)
  *-input:0
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 1
       logical name: input0
       logical name: /dev/input/event0
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:1
       product: Power Button
       physical id: 2
       logical name: input1
       logical name: /dev/input/event1
       capabilities: platform
  *-input:2
       product: Video Bus
       physical id: 3
       logical name: input6
       logical name: /dev/input/event2
       capabilities: platform
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

In trying to grasp the licensing obstacles in obtaining an image, see also [this Open Source stackexchange question](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/q/13204/21026).

Comment: would a virtual machine meet your needs, for "installation in ubuntu"? if not, you can install chromeos on a new partition, and update grub with custom configuration so it detects chromeos. when starting your pc, it should let you choose which operating system to choose

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu are you using? If you want to install ChromeOS in a virtual machine inside your Ubuntu installation, then this question is fine. Dual booting ChromeOS may be off topic here.

Comment: I'm running `22.04 Jammy` and a VM would be great.  That's my preference over dual-boot, anyhow.  @Cagri

Comment: @NicholasSaunders sorry I thought chromeos provided iso downloads, but apparently not. so my previous comment could have some incorrect information. but apparently there are some ways to run chromeos flex (on cloud?) in a vm, maybe check this link out? https://www.digitaltrends.com/computing/how-to-run-chrome-os-in-virtualbox/

Comment: also I checked your other question and that software supports windows, so maybe just installing Windows in a VM is easier? because I'm not sure how virtualbox will handle your USB devices (headset) over network, on a Windows VM you can allow the VM to access your USB devices

Comment: @Cagri Neverware was purchased by Google. The Cloudready ChromeOS" is now google's Chrome OS Flex. The download link in the article you cited does not work anymore.

Comment: I deleted my answer as it looks like there is no easy way to download an ISO for Chrome OS Flex.